# Resize specific view with superview

Tags: macos, cocoa, autolayout

I have this: [image: Typical form style]

Users want to resize the window and I want the description field to resize with super. (Ideally I'd want keywords and description to resize equally but let's not get crazy.)

I managed to make this work in the past by selecting the top half and adding constraints to left-top-right, then selecting the bottom half and adding constraints to left-bottom-right, like this:

[image: Autolayout top half]

[image: Autolayout bottom half]

and then finally

[image: Description fix]

but this suddenly stopped working. The window suddenly only allows resizing horizontally, and not vertically.

Edit: output from `constraintsAffectingLayoutForOrientation:NSLayoutConstraintOrientationVertical` from the description scroll view:

```
(
    "<NSContentSizeLayoutConstraint:0x6100002b5600 V:[NSTextField:0x608000194ec0(17)] Hug:750 CompressionResistance:750>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000098ba0 V:[NSTextField:0x608000194ec0]-(9)-[NSTextField:0x608000195060]>",
    "<NSContentSizeLayoutConstraint:0x6100002b57e0 V:[NSTextField:0x608000195060(17)] Hug:750 CompressionResistance:750>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6080000969e0 V:[NSTextField:0x608000195060]-(72)-[NSTextField:0x6080001949e0]>",
    "<NSContentSizeLayoutConstraint:0x6100002b54e0 V:[NSTextField:0x608000194d20(17)] Hug:750 CompressionResistance:750>",
    "<NSContentSizeLayoutConstraint:0x6100002b53c0 V:[NSTextField:0x608000194b80(17)] Hug:750 CompressionResistance:750>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60800009a0e0 V:[NSTextField:0x608000194910]-(30)-[NSTextField:0x608000194b80]>",
    "<NSContentSizeLayoutConstraint:0x6100002b50c0 V:[NSTextField:0x608000194910(17)] Hug:750 CompressionResistance:750>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60800009a220 V:[NSTextField:0x608000194840]-(NSSpace(8))-[NSTextField:0x608000194910]>",
    "<NSContentSizeLayoutConstraint:0x6100002b4fa0 V:[NSTextField:0x608000194840(17)] Hug:750 CompressionResistance:750>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60800009a3b0 V:|-(22)-[NSTextField:0x608000194840]   (Names: '|':NSView:0x608000128fc0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000099410 NSTextField:0x608000194ec0.baseline == NSTextField:0x608000194f90.baseline>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000098ce0 NSTextField:0x608000194f90.centerY == NSTextField:0x608000194ec0.centerY>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6080000987e0 NSTextField:0x6080001949e0.top == NSScrollView:0x6080001c6ea0.top>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000099730 NSTextField:0x608000194d20.baseline == NSTextField:0x608000194df0.baseline>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000096a30 NSTextField:0x608000194df0.centerY == NSTextField:0x608000194d20.centerY>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000099fa0 NSTextField:0x608000194b80.baseline == NSTextField:0x608000194c50.baseline>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x61000068a870 h=-&- v=-&- V:[NSView:0x608000128fc0]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':NSThemeFrame:0x100350960'PDF Properties' )>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x61000068a8c0 h=-&- v=-&- V:|-(16)-[NSView:0x608000128fc0]   (Names: '|':NSThemeFrame:0x100350960'PDF Properties' )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x610000687d00 'NSWindow-current-height' V:[NSThemeFrame:0x100350960'PDF Properties'(532@500)] priority:500>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000098600 V:[NSScrollView:0x6080001c6f90]-(5)-[NSScrollView:0x6080001c6ea0]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000098b50 V:[NSTextField:0x608000194f90]-(5)-[NSScrollView:0x6080001c6f90]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000098e20 V:[NSTextField:0x608000194df0]-(5)-[NSTextField:0x608000194f90]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6080000991e0 V:[NSTextField:0x608000194c50]-(5)-[NSTextField:0x608000194df0]>"
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those screenshots don't convey much to me. It might be better to show the constraints in the document outline view, but really text would be best. You could add something like this to your code, someplace, and then paste the output into your question:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [_descriptionScrollView constraintsAffectingLayoutForOrientation:NSLayoutConstraintOrientationVertical]);
```

Anyway, I think what you should have are constraints like those represented by this visual format language string (more or less):

```
V:|-titleTextField-6-authorsScrollView(==40)-6-isbnTextField-6-publisherTextField-6-versionTextField-
6-descriptionScrollView(==keywordsScrollView,>=authorsScrollView)-6-keywordsScrollView-6-rightsTextField-
6-licenseTextField-6-licenseURLTextField-6-ccURLTextField-saveMetadataButton-|
```

I broke that across lines to make it easier to read.

The idea is that the vertical distance of everything except the description and keywords scroll views are fixed. The heights of the text fields are intrinsic. The height of the authors scroll view is specified by a height constraint. The distances between the controls are fixed at either the standard distance or a specified distance.

I've specified that the height of the description scroll view equals the height of the keywords scroll view. That way they should evenly divide whatever remains of the window height after all of the other required distances take their cut. I set a minimum height for the scroll views so that the window can't be reduced in height past the point where they are as tall as the authors scroll view.

Not all of the controls are mentioned in my string. The field labels and the "Copy to Clipboard" and "Show License" buttons should be set to share a baseline with the other controls on their lines. Likewise, the image view should be set relative to the license text field.

You need to avoid excess constraints beyond these. You'll over-constrain your layout and that will prevent the window from resizing (or may even result in unsatisfiable constraints). You don't have to do it exactly like I've done, but you shouldn't have more.

Also, just because I've expressed this in code doesn't mean you should do it that way. You can do this in IB. It's just easiest to explain with code-like text.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I clarified what I am doing a bit more in text. I also added the output from the scroll view (the NSTextField's superview.superview) to the question.

Comment: Also, I agree with your visual string but I'm just not sure how to do that in IB.

Comment: It looks to me like you have some extraneous constraints. The labels should not have constraints between them. They should only related to the field that they describe. There are some text fields which are related by both the baseline and the vertical center, which I think is harmlessly redundant since they are a fixed height. To apply my format string, you could clear the existing constraints and then just go step by step establishing the constraints between the relevant objects. If you don't want to clear, select each object and make sure the vertical constraints are just the ones you want.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a sidenote to this as it tripped me up for a long time:

If you have subviews which **cannot be resized vertically**, these will end up pulling the entire thing together. Example of a view which does this is the `NSTextField`.

For example, if you have this set up: `V:|-[textField]-|`, then no matter what you do, the containing view will be shrunk down to ~21 points in height.